# In ag-grid is there way to create different child grids based column. As per the documentation it shows only one child grid per column

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

In the Master-Detail grid documentation, all the example shows only one child grid per row. Is there a way to add multiple child grids for a row based on the column